# How to do search in Users schema in TrueVault?

Tags: android, truevault

In my application a provider will be linked to many clients. Now I want to search all the clients of a particular provider. Both client and providers are storing in user's schema. Can anybody please guide me how to do search in user's schema so that I can get the list of all clients for a particular provider. I searched using SearchUser APi but getting blank document array.
Below is the response that I am getting from the SearchUser API:-

> {   "data": {
>       "documents": [],
>       "info": {
>         "current_page": 0,
>         "num_pages": 0,
>         "per_page": 100,
>         "total_result_count": 0
>       }   },   "result": "success",   "transaction_id": "00745c12-d4e5-4266-a655-d5b6c71819fa" }

Answer (score 0):

I answered this same question on our [discussion forums](https://discuss.truevault.com/t/trustcircle-how-to-do-search-in-users-schema/32), but will repeat here:

For the example you gave, you can use this filter:

`{
  "filter":{
     "username":{
         "type":"eq",
         "value":"+91XXXXXXXXXX"
     }
  }
}`

For a full list of filters available for both Document and User Search, you can reference TrueVault's [API Documentation](https://docs.truevault.com/DocumentSearch#defining-search-options).

Cheers,
Dan